# Тень блока накладывается на соседний блок

Tags: css, box-shadow

У меня есть **неопределённое кол-во блоков** с тенью которые генерируются динамически.
Я размещаю их в нормальном потоке документа и происходит так, что тень нижнего накладывается на верхний. Я пробовал разные махинации с z-index, но ничего не помогло

Как избежать наложения на соседний элемент?

```css
.box { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 19px 38px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 15px 12px;
}

 div.box:nth-child(1) {
   width: 150px;
 }

 div.box:nth-child(3) {
   width: 130px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: А нельзя родителю тени вешать? Так вроде проще

Comment: Overflow:hidden пробовали?

Comment: Слегка поправил код, что бы было нагляднее . Родителя нет т.к. ширина блока может быть разная. В роли родителя выступает переменная которая задаёт общий max-width, но некоторый блоки могут быть другой ширины

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов тогда добавить дочерний элемент с `width: 100%; height: 100%;` и фоном `#fafafa`. задать позиционирование и `z-index`. И в него уже пихать все содержимое, которое предназначалось элементам `.box`

Comment: Пробовал, не работает. z-index отсчитывается от родителя, т.е. следующий ниже блок получит то же значение z-index и перекроет его своей тенью

Comment: @ДенисБеспалов, Возможно неправильно объяснил, сейчас добавлю ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант -- добавить дочерний элемент с `width: 100%; height: 100%;` и фоном `#fafafa`, задать позиционирование и `z-index`. И в него уже пихать все содержимое, которое предназначалось элементам `.box`

```css
.box { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #fafafa;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 19px 38px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 15px 12px;
}

 div.box:nth-child(1) {
   width: 300px;
 }

 div.box:nth-child(3) {
   width: 330px;
 }
 
 .box__inner {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"><div class="box__inner"></div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="box__inner"></div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="box__inner"></div></div>
<div class="box"><div class="box__inner"></div></div>
```

Comment: Я понял почему это сразу не сработало у меня. Это было первое, что я попробовал. Я использую mui библиотеку, а она добавляет свои стили которые создали конфликт. Надо быть осторожнее используя сторонние решения библиотек стилей

Answer (score 0):

Заметил, что проблема в размытии теней с других сторон. Может, стоит сделать её поменьше? (Убавил 38 до 18)

```
.box { 
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 19px 18px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22) 0px 15px 12px;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не подходит. Тень нужно сохранить в исходном варианте

Answer (score 0):

Решил. @Arcadiy навёл на мысль

Мы должны сделать тень с помощью :after а основному блоку поставить `overflow-y: clip;`

Где то видны переходы тени, но это не то, что меня волнует и это уже легко можно поправить, главный вопрос для меня решен - тень не налазит на соседний блок

```css
.box { 
  position:relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow-y: clip;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 30%) 0px 19px 38px, rgb(0 0 0 / 22%) 0px 15px 12px;
    }

 div.box:nth-child(1) {
   width: 300px;
 }

 div.box:nth-child(3) {
   width: 330px;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
```